# How to get data from a REST api call before the application loads

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

I'm trying to make a REST api call before the application loads. From what I believe there are no synchronize REST api calls in Angular/Typescript. So I am unable to get this data before I want to use that data. The reason I'm trying to get data from the REST api call before the application loads is because I have menu items that requires me to check their permissions before I even get those menu items.

For example, in the JSON object below I have a menu item object that is retrieved through a REST api call. Using a RouteGuardService, I navigate to a page, but before I do I check their access by comparing the permissions they have in their token to the permissions that come with the menu item JSON object.

In the second JSON object below is the definition of a route. In the 'canActivate' property it references the RouteGuardService which handles if the user has access to a certain menu.

I've tried checking the permissions on the callback of the REST api call, but am unable to do so since the navigation has already started on load.

JSON Object 1

```
{
                Text: 'Users',
                Tooltip: null,
                Target: '/administration/usermanagement',
                AccessPermissions: ['sys.a'],
                Order: 3,
                CollapsedIcon: 'fa fa-user',
                ExpandedIcon: 'fa fa-user',
                Children: []
            }
```

JSON Object 2

```
{
                        path: 'usermanagement',
                        component: GridUserManagementComponent,
                        data: { title: "User Management" },
                        canActivate: [RouteGuardService]
                    },
```

What I'd hope to happen is have the menu items data load into memory before I go to check if the user is able to access that page. What happens is it goes to a blank gray screen which occurs when it doesn't have access to that page. I recorded the loaded menu items data at the time of the check for access and found it hasn't been filled yet.

EDIT:
Routes definition included in the 'app-routing.module.ts'

```
export const appRoutes: Routes =
[
    {
        path: '',
        component: AppMasterLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            /* Dashboard */
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                component: DashboardComponent,
                data: { title: "Dashboard" },
                canActivate: [RouteGuardService]
            },

            /* Administration */
            {
                path: 'administration',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'security',
                        component: SecurityComponent,
                        data: { title: "Security" },
                        canActivate: [RouteGuardService]
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'localization',
                        component: LocalizationComponent,
                        data: { title: "Localization" },
                        canActivate: [RouteGuardService]
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'template-management',
                        component: TemplateManagementComponent,
                        data: { title: "Template Management" },
                        canActivate: [RouteGuardService]
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'usermanagement',
                        component: GridUserManagementComponent,
                        data: { title: "User Management" },
                        canActivate: [RouteGuardService]
                    },
...
```

Method called to check access in the 'route-guard.service.ts'

```
@Injectable()
export class RouteGuardService implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private jwtService: JwtService, private ccRestApiService: CCRestAPIService) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        let url: string = state.url;

        console.log('AuthGuard canActivate called. url: ' + url);

        return this.isIdentityTokenValid(url) && this.hasAccess(url)
    }
...
```

Comment: Perhaps *ngIf="isNavigationDataLoaded" - set a boolean when your data is loaded. Hide your navigation until then.

Comment: What happens is the navigation loads eventually, but not fast enough if I were to do a refresh. Since refreshing the page will clear the navigation from memory, I have to retrieve it again. Since I have to retrieve it again, I need a way to wait until it's fully retrieve before checking the access still. Let's say if I navigate the '/usermanagement' page and refresh. It should bring me back to the '/usermanagement' page, but is unable to verify the permissions on load since the menu items haven't been loaded into memory yet.

Comment: Every time the service is called to get the data set isNavigationDataLoaded=false until the data is returned. Then set it to true again.

Comment: How are you storing the component and routeguardservice inside the json object. I'm trying to replicate the problem so I can help work on a solution.

Comment: @Mathias I have tried this but seems to check the permissions still before the load of the data

Comment: I have editted the post to give a better idea of what's going on, sorry if I hadn't included this before